# Removing hexadecimal values from XML through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I have to load XML data into SQL Server through SSIS, In XML Source I am getting some hexadecimal symbols so when I am giving that file as a Source in SSIS it is not accepting that Hexadecimal values, how can I parse or remove those (Hexadecimal Symbols).

Error : Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x2 is illegal in XML documents.

Is there any way to remove those using XSLT, If there then please put me in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that XML itself does not allow control-characters, even if encoded as a character entity. XSLT wouldn't be able to parse it either.

XML 1.1 should be able to include the character as an entity, but not as text.

See ["invalid XML file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696424/invalid-xml-file) and ["XML Task error message hexadecimal invalid character"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584711/xml-task-error-message-hexadecimal-invalid-character) for similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Error : Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x2 is illegal in XML
>   documents.
>
> Is there any way to remove those using XSLT, If there then please put
>   me in the right way.

No. This is an XML parser problem -- not an XSLT problem. An XSLT processor only sees the result of parsing an XML document by the specific XML parser it uses.

So, if the XSLT processor in use allows using different XML parsers and you can find an use an XML 1.1 parser, just set up the XSLT processor to use this particular parser.

It may be possible that in XSLT 3.0 (still a working draft) there could be a function that accepts raw text and parses it to an XML document/fragment. Such a function could probably have an argument what type of XML parser to be used -- XML 1.0 or XML 1.1.